# MVC5 Authorize File download MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, authentication, razor, download

I am looking at serving file download in my MVC5 application to users  who have been authorized on login.
I plan to use a physical path structure as below

`App_Data/Files/{ItemName}/{FileName}.{FileExtension}`  (FileExtension is a Zip in most cases)

Asset

```
{**AssetId**, ItemName, FileName, FileExtension, FileLive}
```

ApprovedToDownload

```
{**Id**, **userId**, **AssetId**, GUID, ExpireDate, StartDate}
```

When person gets authorised the userId is linked in the ApprovedToDownload table as above and a dynamic GUID created for access to the file.
The person will download file with url like

```
 /my-assets/download/GUID
```

Controller

```
  [Authorize]
        [Route("my-assets/download/{id}",Name="mydload")]
        [HttpGet]
        public FileContentResult Download(Guid? id)
        {
           int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
          if (id == null) {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not found"); 
            }
            var fzip = db.ApprovedToDownloads.SingleOrDefault(a => a.GUID == id && a.UserId == userId && a.FileLive && a.ExpireDate <= DateTime.Today);

            string fid = id.Value.ToString();
            string fldr=fzip.Asset.ItemName;
            string fnom = fzip.Asset.FileName;
            string fext = fzip.Asset.FileExtension;
            // Read bytes from disk
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files/"+fldr+"/"+fnom+"."+fext));

            return File(fileBytes, "application/zip",  fid+"."+fext);
           }
```

What are my best options for implementing this with security in mind? In other words can anyone advice me if i will face any problems with this and can point me in the direction of best practice.

Answer (score 0):

ActionFilters or RouteConstraints will do the trick I think.